# How do I export to eps in gnuplot for Windows?

Tags: windows, gnuplot, eps

I am running `gnuplot` version 4.6 (patchlevel 0) on Windows XP.  I have placed two files, `data.txt` and `plot.plt` in the same directory.

The contents of `data.txt` are as follows (it is just sin x from 0 to 2 Pi):

```
0.  0.
0.5 0.479425538604203
1.  0.8414709848078965
1.5 0.9974949866040544
2.  0.9092974268256817
2.5 0.5984721441039565
3.  0.1411200080598672
3.5 -0.35078322768961984
4.  -0.7568024953079282
4.5 -0.977530117665097
5.  -0.9589242746631385
5.5 -0.7055403255703919
6.  -0.27941549819892586
```

The contents of `plot.plt` are as follows:

```
set title 'My Brown'
set xlabel 'my x'
set ylabel 'my y'
plot 'data.txt' lc rgb 'brown'
set term postscript eps enhanced "Arial" 24
set output 'example.eps'
```

When I open `plot.plt` in `gnuplot`, the data are indeed plotted.  Moreover, a file `example.eps` is created in the same folder as `data.txt` and `plot.plt`.  However, `example.eps` appears to be blank/empty.  When I right-click on the `example.eps` and then select Properties, it says:

> EPS File
>
> Size: 0 bytes
>
> Size on disk: 0 bytes

When I open `example.eps` in **Adobe Photoshop Elements**, I just see a blank (white) file.

Do you have any thoughts about what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The eps file doesn't get written until a plot command is specified *after specifing the output*. Possible solutions:

- 1) Move your plot command after your `set output` command
- 2) add a `replot` command to the end of your script

The differences in these two approaches are that *1* only creates an `eps` file whereas *2* will create a plot in your default terminal and then re-create the plot in your `eps` file.

In the event that you're not aware, gnuplot can plot functions without datafiles.  To plot `sin(x)`, you just need to do:  `plot sin(x)` -- no datafile necessary.